# Is it OK to use GTK+ for 3D interactive app(e.g. game)?

Tags: 3d, gtk3, interactive

I plan to use GTK+ 3.18 for an application which will include following components, among others:

- **Editor**: will enable users to control and edit 3D content and viewport in a GtkGLArea. But along with the GtkGLArea widget, there will be other widgets in the editor window to edit various properties of the 3D content.
- **Runtime**: this will be a fullscreen window with only a GtkGLArea embedded inside it, but it'll be interactive i.e. users should be able to change viewport and interact with 3D objects using input methods(mouse, keyboard, touch etc.)

Now my question is, should I use GTK+ for such application or I need to use other libraries, especially for the runtime? My points of consideration are following:

1. impact of the overhead of GTK+ on a standalone runtime(GTK+ will provide input handling, sound, OpenGL context etc.)
2. support for various input mechanism(e.g. joystick) in GTK+

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a framework that's more aimed at your use case, such as a game programming toolkit, since you are depending on joystick input. It's possible to use [joysticks with GTK](https://github.com/Grumbel/jstest-gtk/) and of course GL, but a game toolkit would probably give you those things with a lot more convenience.

Comment: Hello, I'm really late to reply, but thanks for the answer. I asked about the joystick input support in GTK+ mailing list, too. What I gather from their replies, GTK+ doesn't have native joystick support and SDL needs to be integrated with GTK, like the library you've linked to. 

My question is would the game programming toolkit provide a rich UI set like GTK+ does? For example, SDL doesn't. I need them for the editor part.

Comment: Depends on the game toolkit. For example, Unity3D does provide a set of UI tools. (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui)